# Any nice way to replace Joda-time's withLaterOffsetAtOverlap method?

Tags: java, jodatime

I have (JDK 7) code written with Joda-time 2.x that uses [withLaterOffsetAtOverlap](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withLaterOffsetAtOverlap--), but I am in a situation where I need to revert to Joda-time 1.6.2 which doesn't have that call. Is there any nice way to replace this without hard-coding actual offsets?

Comment: If you absolutely have to go back, and it's absolutely critical to apply that same logic on the one hour (between 1 AM and 2 AM) of the year where it makes a difference, then look at the source code for Joda-time 2.x, and implement a helper method to do the same thing in Joda-time 1.6.2. That's the advantage of using open-source libraries: You can see what they did. Heck, you can even take the Joda-time 1.6.2 and modify it.

Comment: @Andreas that's interesting..

Comment: This is what I am going with right now.. care to put your response as an answer?

Comment: Not really. It's not an answer, it's a hint to how to come up with the answer yourself.